# Criar banco e tabela com PHP PDO Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde a todos, sou inciante em programação e estou com um problema, estou criando um sistema de cadastro web de lojas, criei uma pagina administrativa para cadastrar as lojas, nessa eu cadastro os dados da loja com nome tipo responsável e usuário e senha para acesso pois cada loja terá um acesso a sua área, agora o problema está sendo que quando crio a loja eu já crio um banco de dados para ela, até isso está ok porem eu quero criar a tabela de produtos ao criar o banco e não consigo, gostaria de saber se é possível criar a tabela logo depois de criar o banco?
estou usando PHP PDO e Mysql.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Pode ser que o banco ainda não esteja pronto, talvez você não consiga criar um logo após o outro.

Comment: o banco cria, mas a tabela não.

Comment: Karlos Fist bem-vindo!! Um post interessante e que irá lhe ajudar nas suas próximas perguntas. Exemplo minimo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Como não fazer perguntas https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas e esse também é interessante https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A sua resposta não responde a sua própria pergunta!!!

**Sim é possível criar a tabela logo depois de criar o banco**

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS lojaDB";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    $sql = "use lojaDB";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRODUTOS (
                ID int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                produto varchar(30) NOT NULL)";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "DB criado com sucesso";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, o problema estava que quando eu criava o banco não tinha nenhum banco selecionado na conexão, então fiz um query selecionando o nome do banco que foi criado e ai ele cria a tabela dentro do banco novo.
Obrigado gente